# About the closure of $]-5, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1 \right\}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

My question about the closure of $A=]-5, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1  \right\}$

Let $A_1=]-5, 0]$ and $A_2=\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n\geq1  \right\}$

We have $ClA_1=[-5, 0]$

and $ClA_2=\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n\geq1  \right\}\cup\{0\}$

***My question is: what is the best writing of closure of A?***

$ClA=[-5, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1  \right\}$.  i.e. adding $\{-5\}$ to $]-5, 0]$

or

$ClA=[-5, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1  \right\}\cup\{0\}$

Where, $ClA$ is the closure of $A$.

Comment: $0$ is already in $]-5,0]$ so we need not add it. So only $-5$ is added to the left interval and the first is the easiest way to write it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you very much